# Add object to existing key in NSuserDefault

Tags: ios, arrays, nsuserdefaults

I want to add the another object to existing key in `NSUserDefault`.

I try this code to add in `NSUserDefault`.

```
delegate.str=[first objectAtIndex:delegate.selectId];
NSLog(@"%@",delegate.str);
delegate.str1=[details1 objectAtIndex:delegate.selectId];
NSLog(@"%@",delegate.str1);     
[delegate.BookMarkDefault setObject:delegate.str forKey:@"Name"];
```

// BookMarkDefault This is NSUSERDefault.

First I will insert `delegate.str` value value successfully goes to `NSUSerDefault`, but when next time adding new value through `delegate.str` for key under `Name` will replace previous value. I want to add new value under the same Key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible if you want to fullfill this kind of requirement then try to use array and then put that array into NSUSerDefault...

Try this code

```
delegate.str=[first objectAtIndex:delegate.selectId];
NSLog(@"%@",delegate.str);
delegate.str1=[details1 objectAtIndex:delegate.selectId];

NSLog(@"%@",delegate.str1);
[yourarray addObject:delegate.str];

NSLog(@"%@",delegate.Bookmarknamearray);
[delegate.BookMarkDefault setObject:youarray forKey:@"Name"];
```

Answer (score 1):

No its not possible to assign multiple values to same key. If you want to use multiple values to same key then use array or dictionary and assign them to the key.

Ex :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:YOUR_ARRAY forKey:@"Name"];
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign two value in single key of NSUserDefaults, you must need to take another `"KEY"` for each value . your can replace pervious value by using following code :

Just try with following code :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: delegate.str forKey:@"Name"];
```

EDITE:

But you can add array in NSUserDefaults, suchlike

```
self.golbalArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObject:@"1", @"2",....,nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: self.golbalArr forKey:@"Name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't save two objects for same key.
In `NSUserDefaults` and `NSDictionary` keys will be unique (There can be only one object for a particular key).

If you need to do this, you can store the values in `NSMutableArray` or `NSDictionary` and add that to the NSUserDefaults like:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dataArray forKey:@"Name"];
```

Comment: You have given the same answer as mine.

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: delegate.str forKey:@"Name"];
```